# php while loop finish sooner

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

i have this code:

```
$nr=10;
       $teste=$this->vector_teste();
       $rezultat=array();
       $k=1;
       do{
         $rand_t=rand(0, count($teste)-1);
         $rand=rand(1,2);
         if($nr<$rand)$rand=1;
         $nr=$nr-$rand;
         $chest=new chestionar(get_cod_by_id($teste[$rand_t]));
         $cnt_q=$chest->numar_intrebari();
         for($i=1;$i<=$rand;$i++){
            $rand_q=rand(1, $cnt_q);
            $rezultat[$teste[$rand_t]][$i]=$rand_q;
         }

         $k++;
       }while($nr>0);
```

and at the end of the code the array $rezultat must have 10 items but, sometimes it have 9 or 8.. and if i'm lucky it have 10 items. Why? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case you can get even 5 items max.

```
$rand=rand(1,2);
if($nr<$rand)$rand=1;
$nr=$nr-$rand;
```

This piece of code decrements `$nr` randomly by 1 or 2. Change it to `$nr--` to always have 10 iterations.